# Using multiple annotations within Xcode

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I would like to provide multiple MapKit annotations (pins) in Xcode 7.0.1 but have no idea how to, I've created one annotation:

```
let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(50.714141, -1.874704)
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = location
annotation.title = "Bournemouth Pier"
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

It seems I can't just copy and paste this code with different titles and coordinates which is really annoying and quite frankly stupid. (you can tell how annoyed I am) any help would be appreciated cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can add multiple annotations this way. Make sure you instantiate a new `MKPointAnnotation` for each one, though.

For example:

```
var location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(50.714141, -1.874704)
var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = location
annotation.title = "Bournemouth Pier"
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.714141, -2.874704)
annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = location
annotation.title = "Gwernesney"
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

If you're still having trouble adding multiple annotations, please edit your question, showing us how you are trying to do that. You've shown an attempt at adding a single annotation, but not how you've attempted to add multiple ones.